# API Gateway CORS Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

So I have CORS enabled going through the basic setup given by AWS Gateway. However for this API I need to allow Control Origins for all requests and allow credentials.

Here is what it looks like

[image]

The issue as you may have guessed is this setup is not allowed by CORS, you can not have a wildcard for Origin and have credentials as true. Normally the work around for this is to just grab the requesting domain and add it into the Origin Header. Which is more or less what I want to do. But I don't know how to get that information and add it as a mapping value. Where does API Gateway store that information and how do i get it?

UPDATE:
I have to pass through HTTP Header Host to my Lambda Function which I should have mentioned earlier, I have tried implementing the Answer below but I cannot access the header to pass it to the Lambda function using the instructions provided. Any more assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. We just recently added support for passing through the 'Host' and 'User-Agent' headers this week. Could you try accessing these headers again? Please let me know if it worked for you. Thanks, Jurgen - API Gateway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay After hours of research and finding bits of information across the internet I have a solution and hopefully it is useful for other people.

To pass an HTTP Header that is not a default value provided by AWS API Gateway and then access that data via a Lambda Function and return that data in the Response Header follow the steps below

1. In "Method Request" go to "HTTP Request Headers" and add your desired header to capture. ie. if we want to get the host value of the API url you can enter "Host" here. if you want to get the website host of the caller use "Origin"
2. In "Integration Request" go to mapping templates and create a new template if an "application/json" does not exist, if it does just update it.

This is the important part, pass the header value you set in step 1. To do that write something similar to the following in the Template Box.

```
{
   "origin" : "$input.params().header.Origin",
   "host" : "$input.params().header.Host"
}
```

You can also pass in any url parameters you have defined in the same JSON.

3. Access the data from Lambda, The integration request passed the information into the "Event" parameter if using Node as the Lambda Backend code. to retrieve the value of any header just use the following within your handler.

   ```
   event.origin;
   ```
4. When sending back your response from Lambda to API Gateway, it is best to format the response in JSON. Something similar to this.

   ```
   { 
      "origin" : event.origin,
      "host" : event.host,
      "nonHeaderOutput" : "Hello World"
   }
   ```
5. In "Integration Response" go to "Header Mappings", if the header you need is not listed you may add it in "Method Response" and it will then appear here. For this example I used "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and edited the Mapping Value to be `integration.response.body.origin`
6. now go to "Mapping Templates and select the content type you want to use, and then edit the template to access the non header responses by adding this to the Template Box

   ```
   $input.path("$.nonHeaderOutput")
   ```

That is it now the header that was sent to the API can be used in your method Response.

Comment: If I'm implementing your solution, do I need to modify the client code in any way? I receive the message `Uncaught Host must be defined` when I attempt to call the newly deployed resource.

Comment: They have made a few updates since this was written last year, but the theory still holds, I would need to know more about what exactly you are trying to do to help you with it.

Comment: It's not necessary, I determined that the CORS error was actually just a permissions error being falsely flagged as a CORS error.

Comment: I faced the problem today and implemented a similar solution in a lambda function: https://gist.github.com/vtellier/9acb579f81e1a817e182122e8ac2a995

Comment: Another workaounrd is this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related might help, but it is not really serious...

Answer (score 3):

Jurgen from API Gateway here.
Thanks for reporting this issue. There is currently no simple way to set it up via the "Enable CORS" feature in the console. However, we are looking into it to improve the user experience for this use case.

As a potential workaround, you could passthrough the Origin header from the client to your backend and parse / create the value for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header there. Then you would map the Header in the Integration Response from 'integration.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to Access-Control-Allow-Origin and return it to the client.

Hope this helps.

Best,
Jurgen

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I can just pass the value with the rest of my response and handle it there.

Comment: Follow Up question. How would I pass through the Origin Header, ie, what API variable is that contained in.

Comment: You need to specify the Origin header in the method request. In the integration request you can access it via method.request.header.Origin. For the integration response you would use integration.response.header.XYZ. You can have a look on how to setup method request and response headers here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings.html#how-to-method-settings-execution-console

Comment: I'm going out of my goddamned mind trying to get this to work. I need to have `widthCredentials` set for my xhr request in order to send the Cookie header, but I can't set that using api gateway because I can't set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`. How the hell do I work around this?

Comment: This caught me out today too.  Turns out that Jurgen's workaround here is STILL NECESSARY if you want to use your own CORS validation instead of AWS's "allow everything with a pretend check" default.
Simply add "Origin" to the request passed-through headers, and add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the response passed-through headers.(and other headers as necessary in your situation)