# AWS API Gateway CORS issue

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

i've made an api gateway with a lambda function, the api works fine over rest clients, and over browser.
when i created a api key and made it obligatory for the post request, it works fine over rest client but no more over the browser, it sais

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

this by knowing that all CORS are activated, and "X-Api-Key" is in the cors headers

Comment: You probably want to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45523133/edit to edit/update your question to show the code you're using to make the request, as well as show the full response you're getting in each case, including the response headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API Gateway CORS Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277679/api-gateway-cors-issue)

Answer (score -1):

[Enable CORS in AWS API Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei7mZ.png)

from **API Gateway** choose the API resource or method and click on the **Actions** button, it will display a list of options. Select **Enable CORS** options from the options and deploy the API by choosing **Deploy API** option. It will enable CORS to the selected Resource or Method.

note: I don't have enough reputation to embed the image in answer that's why the image link is provided.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Read carefully the question please !! The CORS are activated and even I got the issue